# Navigate to a child route by default angular

Tags: angular

I am trying to navigate to a child route by default so here are my routes:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '', --> /config
    redirectTo: 'branding',
    component: ConfigurationComponent,
    children: [
      { path: 'branding', component: BrandingComponent },
      { path: 'channel-branding', component: ChannelBrandingComponent },
      { path: 'date-time', component: DateTimeSettingsComponent },
      { path: 'graph', component: GraphSettingsComponent },
      { path: 'grid', component: GridSettingsComponent },
      { path: 'labels', component: LabelSettingsComponent }
    ]
  },
];
```

the parent route is `/config` and the children are `/config/branding` etc I would like to go to `/config/branding` by default if someone navigates to `/config`. I tried using `redirectTo` but that seems to break all the things. How can I get this behavior?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add the redirection in your children array, like this

```js
 children: [
      { path: '', redirectTo: 'branding' },
      { path: 'branding', component: BrandingComponent },
      { path: 'channel-branding', component: ChannelBrandingComponent },
      { path: 'date-time', component: DateTimeSettingsComponent },
      { path: 'graph', component: GraphSettingsComponent },
      { path: 'grid', component: GridSettingsComponent },
      { path: 'labels', component: LabelSettingsComponent }
    ]
```

Thanks.